# YouTube Data API returns an inconsistent viewCount value compared to the value depicted on the UI

Tags: google-apis-explorer

For example the following channel
https://www.youtube.com/user/kidrauhl
has 21,454,838,559 views in the about section.

However, when I use the channels.list method of the API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) the viewCount in the statistics part of the response is totally different:

```
"statistics": {
        "viewCount": "994127449",
        "commentCount": "0",
        "subscriberCount": "54000000",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "172"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.viewCount

According to the docs, it says:

```
statistics.viewCount  
The number of times the channel has been viewed.
```

So I'm guessing the view count on the about page is the number of combined views for all the videos, and the **statistics.viewCount** is the number of views the channel page has accumulated.

Comment: That would be a valid answer if this mismatch between two value was prevalent in all channels. But it appears only for very popular channels having view count somewhere between 15-16 billions on the UI. I suppose it's a big number truncation issue. For less popular channels the two counts are pretty close, and I suppose the difference can be attributed on synchronization.